# Compute columnwise conditional distributions from dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Please feel free to modify the *Title* of that question.

I have a `data.frame` with three *labeld* variables.

```
require(Hmisc)

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(var1=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE),
                 var2=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE),
                 var3=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE))
label(df$var1) <- "One"
label(df$var2) <- "Two"
label(df$var3) <- "Three"
```

I want to calculate the percentage and display them combined together like this

```
         0    1 <NA>
One   0.27 0.37 0.36
Two   0.29 0.41 0.30
Three 0.45 0.31 0.24
```

The code below does work. But my question is how can I simplify this code? The names of the variables are numbered. You could do this to get all relevant variables

```
names(df)[startsWith(names(df), "var")]
```

The **point** is that the number of variables are variable/flexibel. ;)
I get them by there name prefix (in this example just `var`). The real data has variables like this: `v3_5_*`, `v4_1_*`, ...

Any idea or hint?

This is the full working (but not simplified) code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(var1=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE),
                 var2=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE),
                 var3=sample(c(0, 1, NA), 100, replace=TRUE))
label(df$var1) <- "One"
label(df$var2) <- "Two"
label(df$var3) <- "Three"

t1 <- table(df$var1, useNA="always")
t1 <- 100 / sum(t1) * t1 / 100

t2 <- table(df$var2, useNA="always")
t2 <- 100 / sum(t2) * t2 / 100

t3 <- table(df$var3, useNA="always")
t3 <- 100 / sum(t3) * t3 / 100

m <- rbind(t1, t2, t3)
rownames(m) <- c(label(df$var1),
                 label(df$var2),
                 label(df$var3))
```

Comment: where does `label` function come from?

Comment: @mt1022 I don't know. It is R-inbuild.

Comment: `help(label)` told me that it comes from `Hmisc`. I don't know why it is loaded by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to run `table` on the columns using `apply`

```
m <- apply(df, MAR = 2, table, useNA = "always")
m <- t(prop.table(m, margin = 2))
rownames(m) <- sapply(df, label)
```

where `prop.table(m, margin = 2)` calculates column elements divided by column sums (essentially what e.g. `t1 / sum(t1)` is doing above) and `label` comes from the `Hmisc` package.  We get:

```
m
#          0    1 <NA>
# One   0.27 0.37 0.36
# Two   0.29 0.41 0.30
# Three 0.45 0.31 0.24
```

Comment: Awesome. R is so great. But it is hard to think the R-way. ;) Do you have an idea for a better Title of my Question so that this can be helpfull for other readers, too?

Comment: Since your desired output is a conditional distribution table (i.e. the distribution of {0, 1, NA} conditional on column being "One", "Two", ..., perhaps your title could be something like "Compute columnwise conditional distributions from dataframe". I don't think the fact that your values are dichotomous really matters to this question (e.g. you could have 0, 1, 2, ..., NA, and the approach would still be the same).

Answer (score 1):

Use `table` as you have already done so:

```
rbind(
  as.numeric(table(df[,1], useNA = "always")), 
  as.numeric(table(df[,2], useNA = "always")), 
  as.numeric(table(df[,3], useNA = "always")))/100
```

Comment: @buhtz how simplified do you want your code, this is simpler than what you did, but there's probably simpler options still...